# Why bootstrap compile CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

As a front-end beginnger, when I read the bootstrap document, I'm confused about this part...

> Compiling CSS and JavaScript
>
> Bootstrap uses Grunt for its build system, with convenient methods for
>   working with the framework. It's how we compile our code, run tests,
>   and more.

Can anyone tell me why there's a need to compile CSS & JS?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses CSS preprocessors like SASS or LESS. This preprocessors give some "syntactic sugar" to you, that means you can write complex CSS or repetitive CSS in a more comfortable way but in the end browsers don't undersand .sass or .less files, so first you must translate those files to the corresponding CSS files. That's what they mean with "compile".

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has two forms to be downloaded. The first one is download it as a compressed file. This one contains all the structure of the framework (its JavaScript files or CSS files minified...). The second form, is downloading the basic structure of Bootstrap and by using grunt task runner, you generate the final (or your final) CSS or JS files as well as the framework does.

Answer (score 0):

in simple words, compiling the css or javascript means making them understandable for browser. for example if you introduce new syntax `|div| hello world |div|`  for html instead of " `<div> hello world </div>` ". now the browser is not able to understand |div| and you have to compile it, in other word converting all "||" into " < >".